# reactjs conditional render works after second click

Tags: reactjs

I have three components: MyDashboard, MyContent, MyForm.

The MyDashboard component starts off by rendering the MyContent component as a child. I have a button within the MyContent component which when clicked should swap out the component with the MyForm component.

Clicking the button flashes the MyForm component on the first click, then goes straight back to the MyContent component. After the second click however the MyForm component is rendered and stays rendered.

MyDashboard:

```
function MyDashboard(props) {
  const [viewForm, setViewForm] = useState(false); // Don't show the form initially

  const handleClick = () => {
    setViewForm(!viewForm);
  };

  return (
    <div>
            {(() => {
              if (viewForm) { // conditionally render the form or the content
                return <MyForm {...props} />;
              } else {
                return (
                  <MyContent
                    {...props}
                    setViewForm={handleClick}
                    viewForm={viewForm}
                  />
                );
              }
            })()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyContent:

```
function MyContent(props) {

  return (
    <p>
        <a href="#" onClick={props.setViewForm}> // need to click this twice to render the form.
          Show the form
        </a>
    </p>
  );
}

export default MyContent;
```

MyForm:

```
function MyForm({ props, location }) {

// form setup 


  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Form>
         //... the form
        </form>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors logged in the terminal when running this? I notice you have <Form> ... </form> in the MyForm function which may cause an error.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the `<a />` tag with a `button` in the `MyContent` component...?? I suspect the `href=#` having something to do with it...

Comment: Not sure if the IFFE you are trying to do is causing some weird scoping issues, but you can just use a ternary in the render and get rid of the IFFE


`{viewForm ? 
    <MyForm {...props} /> : 
    <MyContent {...props} setViewForm={handleClick} viewForm={viewForm} />
}`

Comment: Thanks @KwameOpareAsiedu this is what it was. I change the `<a href=#` with a `<Button>` and it no longer does it.

Comment: You're so very welcome... Glad I could be of help...